# This request requires a matching csrf cookie and header. 353 code error on twitter

Tags: c#, cookies, csrf

My script can't follow on twitter anymore. It gives this error:
This request requires a matching csrf cookie and header.

I added this header:

```
request.Headers.Add("x-csrf-token", token);
```

And this to edit token in the cookie:

```
cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("ct0", token) { Domain = request.RequestUri.Host });
```

But it still doesn't work anymore. What should I do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I am using python to do exact the same thing and I noticed that there are some other headers you should add:

```
Bearer = 'Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPYXBAAAAAAACLXUNDekMxqa8h%2F40K4moUkGsoc%3DTYfbDKbT3jJPCEVnMYqilB28NHfOPqkca3qaAxGfsyKCs0wRbw'
session.headers['Authorization'] = Bearer
session.headers['x-twitter-auth-type'] = 'OAuth2Session'
session.headers['X-Twitter-Active-User'] = 'yes'
session.headers['Origin'] = 'https://twitter.com'
```

I found that Bearer string from this file which loaded in html request:

```
https://abs.twimg.com/k/en/init.en.37d4e85afd8ede9741dd.js
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much bro. But I already added those headers, but my code still gives this "This request requires a matching csrf cookie and header." issue on http analyzers. And I realized that Bearer string never changes on twitter it's always the same. But what is that crsf cookie and header issue. Please help me ASAP. Does your code follow successfully on twitter?

Comment: Maybe if I get the right token from the cookies which "ct0" in the cookies, and add it to the header as csrf token, it can successfully follow then. But I really don't know how to get a specific cookie. Do you know it?

Comment: Yes, the Bearer string is the same. 
I am using that "ct0" cookie as csrf token every time and the following is okay so far. I am using Python so the code to get this cookie is as follows: 

ck = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)
self.session.headers['x-csrf-token'] = ck['ct0']

Comment: Hi again, nextstack. I had figured out the problem months ago by getting the csrf token from the webrequest's cookie header and adding to the header again as csrf. So that worked for me. But now I am having the same issue again, this time it doesn't generate ct0 token value even on the second request try. What about you, does your follow code still work?